# pypdf errors - module object has no attribute number

Tags: python, pypdf

here's the code I am using

```
import os
import decimal
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader
path = r"E:\python\Real Python\Real Python\Course materials\Chapter 8\Practice files"
inputFileName = os.path.join(path,"Pride and Prejudice.pdf")
inputFile = PdfFileReader(file(inputFileName,"rb"))

print "Number of pages:", inputFile.getNumPages()
print "Title:", inputFile.getDocumentInfo().title
```

Now, when I run this code I am getting an error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'Number'
```

I took a screenshot of the whole output that I got
when I run the above code, with errors and everything.
so,please take a look and let me know what's wrong?

[image]

After I used `import decimal` in the code,
I got a few errors.
So, I took a screenshot of the whole thing and am attaching it here.
[image]

Comment: Your code works fine on my system... Try `import decimal` and see if you have an error. If so, that file might be broken.. you might also post it in your question...

Comment: Okay, I tried the import decimal and still getting errors.

Comment: Could you post your traceback for `import decimal` (in case you don't know, it's the text before the error... like `File blah blah...`).

Comment: I just posted a screenshot of the whole thing in my original post. please take a look.

Comment: would love it if someone could help out.

Answer (score 0):

pyPdf is now renamed to `pypdf` and a couple of other classes / methods were renamed. I'm the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2.

Another change was that we dropped using `decimal`. Instead, we now use the built-in `float`. Hence this error will not occur in later versions of `pypdf`.